# setting a drawText object visible and invisible android

Tags: java, android, canvas, touch-event

I want to set a drawText object visible and invisible with just a click. It'll start as invisible but when the user tap anywhere on the screen, the object will appear and vice versa, after tapping again the object will be invisible again.

Here's my code

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if (GetterSetter.isVisible) {

            renderText(canvas);

        }
}

private void renderText(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setTextSize(18);
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        textPaint.setARGB(0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
        canvas.drawText(GetterSetter.currLoc, 16, 50, textPaint);

    }
```

here's my onTouchEvent

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();

        switch (e.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (GetterSetter.counter < 1) {
                GetterSetter.counter++;
                GetterSetter.isVisible = true;
            } else {
                GetterSetter.counter = 0;
                GetterSetter.isVisible = false;
            }
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

and here are my constants: GetterSetter.java

```
public static String currLoc = "Hello World";

    public static boolean isVisible = false;

    public static int counter = 0;
```

My problem is, its not working. I don't know how should I make it work aside from what I've done so far.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the fact that if it is not visible, set it to visible and vise versa. And don't use `static` declaration for isVisible since you want to change it.

```
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (!GetterSetter.isVisible) {
            GetterSetter.isVisible = true;
        } else {
            GetterSetter.isVisible = false;
        }
        break;
```

Answer (score 1):

make the `View` to draw it contents when you change the value of `isVisible` value by calling `invalidate()`... and as you want to listen for tap event, use `ACTION_UP` event instead of `ACTION_MOVE`...

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();
    switch (e.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        GetterSetter.isVisible = !GetterSetter.isVisible;
        invalidate();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: what's the use of invalidate() ?

Comment: @ChristianBurgos documentation will clearly expalin you... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29

Comment: it said it can't be called from a non-UI thread... it can't be called on the onTouchEvent